# How to split a string into equal parts in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I have an input file ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX. Using pig commands how can i generate a text file which will look like this.
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
MNO etc.

#### Edit: Further clarification

I have a file which contains data of String data type in a single row. I want to split this string according to the length defined by the user.

For example a string might be asdfghjklasdfghjkl and user defines the string length as 4.

Then I would want my output to be asdf ghjk lasd fghj and so on. Also I want this job to be map reducible as the input data will be of huge size.

Comment: Write a custom UDF to get the job done.

Comment: Define equal? Is the length going to be 3 always?

Comment: No its not going to be always 3 it may vary.

Comment: @ShreyasKothavade please clarify what are do you mean ? if it's a primary number ?

Answer (score 0):

This question is very unclear regarding what is exactly required.

So without going into specifics, here is what I would do:

1. Write a simple python function that takes in a line and splits it in 'equal parts'
2. In pig, stream through this user defined function

## Update after comment that the complete input is 1 line

I don't think Pig is equipped to handle this efficiently as you have only 1 input line, and pig parallelizes by distributing (input) lines.

However, your operation is so simple, that one would expect that even a simple loop without mapreduce could be fast enough, consider giving that a try. (Afterwards you will have many short lines, and Pig could be perfect at handling that in further steps).

Comment: The thing is, I have a file which contains data of String data type in a single row. I want to split this string according to the length defines by the user. For example a string might be asdfghjklasdfghjkl and user defines the string length to be 4. Then I would want my output to be asdf ghjk lasd fghj and so on. Also I want this job to be map reducible as the input data will be of huge size. What do i do ?

Comment: @ShreyasKothavade I have updated my answer, as I don't think pig is the way to go here.